# Grails 2.3.4 run-app not working

Tags: grails-2.0

I am installing grails 2.4.0.m1 on Red Hat Linux platform and trying to execute run-app.
It is failing with error

```
home/jdk1.7.0/bin/original-java-binary-wrapper: No such file or directory
```

Not sure what is it that I am doing wrong here?

The same happened even during grails 2.4.7.
Any pointers on how this works?

Answer (score 0):

if ggts is 64 then java installation must be 64 bit.if it is 32 bit, ggts also be 32 bit. and check java is installed correctly and check path for java. Did you set environment variable for java.[See this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207552/no-such-file-or-directory-when-invoking-java)